# What is the difference between Input and Shuffle Read

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, shuffle

I was looking for a formula to optimize the `spark.shuffle.partitions` and came across this [post](https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/artificial-intelligence/blogs/spark-performance-optimization-guidelines/)
It mentions `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = quotient (shuffle stage input size/target size)/total cores) * total cores`

When i look at the stages in my job I see input and Shuffle read (screenshot below). What is the difference between them?
And would shuffle stage input size here actually mean `Input` ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Spark UI is documented here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/web-ui.html

The relevant paragraph reads:

- Input: Bytes read from storage in this stage
- Output: Bytes written in storage in this stage
- Shuffle read: Total shuffle bytes and records read, includes both data read locally and data read from remote executors
- Shuffle write: Bytes and records written to disk in order to be read by a shuffle in a future stage

Comment: Ah, So the `Shuffle stage input size` mentioned in the blog is actually `Shuffe Read` then.